# Trying to configure the Selenium in IntelliJ IDEA, could able to execute it but could not able to configure Maven

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, selenium-chromedriver

Came across this error:

```
java: error: release version 5 not supported

Module SeleniumMavenNew_latest SDK 16 does not support source version 1.5.
```

Help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Do you have source and target language level set in your pom.xml?